# How to update my forks of Evernote SDK for Python to track latest updates?

Tags: python, evernote

First of all, I'm hoping that Evernote will start maintaining its Python SDK ([evernote/evernote-sdk-python for Python 2](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python) and [evernote/evernote-sdk-python3 for Python 3](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python3)). In the meantime, I'm looking for advice on how to update my forks of these SDK to bring them up-to-speed with the latest changes in the [Evernote API](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/).  Specifically:

1. Can someone from Evernote indicate whether these SDKs will be supported or are we on our own?
2. For [evernote/evernote-sdk-python for Python 2](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python), it looks like a good place to start is to merge the [matthewayne/evernote-sdk-python](https://github.com/matthewayne/evernote-sdk-python) fork and then pick and choose from the [outstanding pull requests](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python/pulls).  Has someone already gone down this path?
3. For (https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python) and [evernote/evernote-sdk-python3 for Python 3](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python3)), has anyone tried [Merge latest python2 sdk by ahxxm · Pull Request #11 · evernote/evernote-sdk-python3](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python3/pull/11/files)?
4. Where can I find the latest Thrift IDL files for Evernote?  [evernote/evernote-thrift: Thrift IDL files for the Evernote Cloud API](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-thrift) hasn't been updated since June 2013 (to match version 1.25 of the Evernote API. (Are we up to [version 1.28](https://github.com/matthewayne/evernote-sdk-python/commit/2cf00691aec81ea94b3ed401af8a8d4660986080) at the very least of the API?)  BTW, what is the current version number of the API?
5. How do I go about compiling the Thrift IDL files into Python code for the Evernote SDK?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We haven't put too much work into our SDKs lately but we're hoping to change that in the coming weeks. As a first step we (finally) updated our [API reference](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/) (another, minor update coming soon) and the next step is our SDKs. There's a lot of work to do here, since we have SDKs for quite a few languages, and the few of us that are working on this stuff are doing so in between core product work. Part of that is adding newly generated thrift files, so you shouldn't need to worry about that.

Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Thanks for answering, I've also found out recently the API reference was updated but Thrift IDL and SDKs are still based on 1.25 API version. Could you please share the newish Thrift IDL files _before_ you adapt each and every SDK for them? I am a maintainer of one [library](https://github.com/d1vanov/QEverCloud) which sources are generated from the Thrift IDL files. I need the new version to migrate my own "SDK" to the new API.

Comment: Sure, I have some time this weekend, will work on that. If it's easier I can also provide you with files generated by running the thrift compiler on the IDL. You can probably guess my email address from my SO username and the fact that I work at Evernote...

Comment: Thanks, emailed you :)

Comment: It's ten months since I posed my question, and I see that the https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python3 is still on v 1.25. Any estimate of when the SDK will be updated to 1.28?